# Execução de procedure com argumento do tipo data em uma dblink

Tags: oracle, procedure, sybase

ao executar a procedure abaixo, via DBLINK no Oracle

```
corporativo..UP_COP025_ASS_DMANDA_JURID_I 17444968, 1, "1", "20150806", "RJ", " ", " ", "000020"
```

recebo o erro:

> erro: Syntax error during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value
>   '"20150806"' to a DATE field.

Devo transcrever o comando da procedure, substituindo "(aspas) por plics (')?

```
corporativo..UP_COP025_ASS_DMANDA_JURID_I 17444968, 1, '1', '20150806', 'RJ', ' ', ' ', '000020'
```

Abraços,

Answer (score 1):

Como se tratava de uma dificuldade de um fornecedor, eu quis compartilhar a dúvida antes de apresentar a sugestão que eu achava mais correta.

Pois bem, a chamada no Sybase funciona plenamente neste formato:
corporativo..UP_COP025_ASS_DMANDA_JURID_I 17444968, 1, "1", "20150806", "RJ", " ", " ", "000020"

Onde o campo "20150806" é um tipo data na assinatura da procedure.
Se for chamar do mesmo modo no Oracle, através de uma DBlink dá erro neste campo data, com a mensagem Syntax error during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value '"20150806"' to a DATE field.

Sugeri, que ao invés de usar aspas duplas neste campo "simulando" uma data, usar aspas simples ('). Me recordava de algo assim na minha época de oracle.

O fornecedor implementou a sugestão e funcionou sem problemas.

Ficando assim:
corporativo..UP_COP025_ASS_DMANDA_JURID_I 17444968, 1, "1", '20150806', "RJ", " ", " ", "000020"

Abraços, e obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Teria que saber a estrutura da sua `Procedure`, e da tabela, mas tente adicionar o comando `to_date`, pois assim você converte sua *string* em *date*:

```
corporativo..UP_COP025_ASS_DMANDA_JURID_I 17444968, 1, '1', to_date('20150806','yyyymmdd'), 'RJ', ' ', ' ', '000020'
```